# Referenced DLL. In root, move to folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have several DLLs referenced in my project. On build, they get dumped to the root directory.

How do I set a folder to which to copy these to and have the project reference them from the folder?

Basically, I want my output to have a folder called "whatever" and have my app reference them from the folder instead of the root.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your DLLs to the folder (source folder, as you have described).  Then set your references to get the DLLs from that folder.  (remove current reference, add reference, browse to your preferred folder).

In the /project/references (for the DLLs you have mentioned) set the property "Copy Local" to False.

Comment: Do I move the DLLs to the [output folder]\Bin or the [source folder]\Bin ? As in, do I reference them from the folder where the output gets dumped or do I reference them from the project source folder?

Comment: referenced the DLLs from the source\Bin folder and the project builds but does not run. Process just ends on launch

Comment: For your project to work/run, you will need those DLLs to either be 1) in the GAC or 2) in the (output) /bin folder.

Comment: Fyi, when I work on a project (like yours) that uses custom DLLs, I keep a /DLL folder in my Solution folder (adjacent to my project folder). It makes it a little easier to manage the DLLs (for source control, backups, deployments, etc). It sounds like you are doing the same.